# Python the code in multithreading could not work

Tags: python, multithreading

Here i'm trying to make socket file transfer in python. And i made a

TCP listener:

```
def tcp_listener(server_port, state):
    server_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
    server_socket.setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    server_socket.bind(('', port))
    server_socket.listen(20)
    # state['tcp_listener'] = STATE_READY
    while True:
        client_socket, addr = server_socket.accept()
        print('New connection from', addr)
        thread = Thread(target=sub_connection, args=(client_socket, addr))
        thread.daemon = True
        thread.start()
```

to accept the connection from client. It works quite well when it is not in the Thread. However, cause I also need to have other while loops, like a file scanner to monitor the new file in a folder. I tried to run them by using thread. And

```
thread = Thread(target=tcp_listener, args=(port, state))
    thread.daemon = True
    thread.start()
```

The result is [image]

It doesn't work at all. So i'm really confused. Hope you guys could offer me some help.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have imported threading

and used `threading.Thread`  when you call the Thread here  instead of just 'Thread':

```
  `thread = Thread(target=sub_connection, args=(client_socket, addr))`
```

Comment: Ok, i have tried it, it still doesn't work. In fact, two days ago, my code worked very well. It is really confusing

Comment: Perhaps the python version that's running your code is outdated. Try running the code using python3.9 filename.py .